# Timing accuracy with swift using GCD dispatch_after

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to create a metronome for iOS in Swift. I'm using a GCD dispatch queue to time an AVAudioPlayer. The variable machineDelay is being used to time the player, but its running slower than the time I'm asking of it.

For example, if I ask for a delay of 1sec, it plays at 1.2sec. 0.749sec plays at about 0.92sec, and 0.5sec plays at about 0.652sec. I could try to compensate by adjusting for this discrepancy but I feel like there's something I'm missing here.

If there's a better way to do this altogether, please give suggestions. This is my first personal project so I welcome ideas.

Here are the various functions that should apply to this question:

```
func milliseconds(beats: Int) -> Double {

    let ms = (60 / Double(beats))
    return ms
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if self.playState == false {
        return
    }

    playerPlay(playerTick, delay: NSTimeInterval(milliseconds(bpm)))
}

func playerPlay(player: AVAudioPlayer, delay: NSTimeInterval) {

    let machineDelay: Int64 = Int64((delay - player.duration) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, machineDelay),dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        player.play()    
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never really done anything with sound on iOS but I can tell you why you are getting those inconsistent timings.

What happens when you use `dispatch_after()` is that some timer is set somewhere in the OS and at some point soon after it expires, it puts your block on the queue. "at some point after" is going to be short, but depending on what the OS is doing, it will almost certainly not be close to zero.

The main queue is serviced by the main thread using the run loop. This means your task to play the sound is competing for use of the CPU with all the UI functionality. This means that the chance of it playing the sound immediately is quite low.

Finally, the completion handler will fire at some short time after the sound finishes playing but not necessarily straight away.

All of these little delays add up to the latency you are seeing. Unfortunately, depending on what the device is doing, that latency can vary. This is never going to work for something that needs precise timings.

---

There are, I think, a couple of ways to achieve what you want. However, audio programming is beyond my area of expertise. You probably want to start by looking at [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html). My five minutes of research suggests either Audio Queue Services or OpenAL, but those five minutes are literally everything I know about sound on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

dispatch_after is not intended for sample accurate callbacks.

If you are writing audio applications there is no way to escape, you need to implement some CoreAudio code in one way or another.

It will "pull" specific counts of samples. Do the math (figuratively ;)